# Give a Qt application a name which shows up in alt-tab window switch list

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu, desktop

I have a PyQt5 application. I call `QApplication.setApplicationName("my-name")` and this appears as the default window title, but when I alt-tab through my programs (on Ubuntu 18.04 standard configuration) the application name is "Unknown"

[image]

What's missing? How do I make the application name appear here? (An icon would also be nice, but the name is most important.)

Cross-platform if possible.

Comment: I think those icons and names come from .desktop files installed in the system.

Comment: On my app, the name comes from the Window's `title` property.

Comment: QWindow also has a setIcon function, but I haven't tried it.